# How can I use spies with Jest in order to test a NodeJs module/app

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I don't understand how to spy whether a method/function has been fired inside a module.
This is my example:

**db.js**

```
module.exports.saveUser = (user) => {
    console.log('Saving the user', user);
};
```

**app.js**

```
let db = require('./db');

module.exports.handleSignup = (email, password) => {
    db.saveUser({ email, password });
}
```

**app.test.js**

```
const db = require('./db');
jest.genMockFromModule('./app');
const app = require('./app');

describe('App: ', () => {
    it('should call "db.saveUser" with a user object', () => {
        let dbSpy = jest.spyOn(db, 'saveUser');
        const user = { email: 'email@email.com', password: 'abc123' };
        app.handleSignup(user.email, user.password);
        expect(dbSpy).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

by running this test I can see from the shell the console.log written in saveUser(), so it means that db.saveUser() is firing and Jest is not mocking up saveUser().
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

referring to the manual mock example given here:
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html

`jest.genMockFromModule()` is actually called in a mock module file.  Even so, if that db file you're mocking is one of your own local files, you wouldn't need to call genMockFromModule.  I believe that that's only used for the npm modules in your `node_modules` folder and core modules (e.g. 'fs', 'readline', etc.)

**that aside**

I've been working with Spock for a while and I've found mocking and observing to be a bit of a trial-and-error process. Sometimes you have to get a bit creative with it as it doesn't quite perform as you might expect.

An easy approach that has worked for me in multiple instances (and, I imagine, will work in your case):

create a mock:
`./__mocks__/db.js` (I'm assuming db.js is in your project's base dir folder)

```
module.exports = {
  fileSaveObserver: [],
  getFileSaveObserver () {
    return this.fileSaveObserver;
  },
  saveUser (obj) { 
    this.fileSaveObserver.push(obj);
  }
}
```

then in `./__tests__/app.test.js`:

```
jest.mock('./db.js');
const app = require('../app');

describe('App: ', () => {
  test('should call "db.saveUser" with a user object', () => { 
    const user = { email: 'email@email.com', password: 'abc123' };
    app.handleSignup(user.email, user.password);
    const db = require('./db.js');
    const observer = db.getFileSaveObserver()
    expect(observer.length).toBe(1)
    expect(observer).toEqual(user);
  })
```

if you're having problems with the above, try removing the '.js' file extensions from the jest.mock() statement and the require statement (this has been a gotcha for me on some occasions.

hope that helps!